# Access the error response without modifying the Amplify library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, aws-amplify

I am using the AWS Amplify library to handle the login on my React app. This works by wrapping the entire app in a HOC, and I have added custom UIs for the login screens. By default Amplify displays error messages from Cognito in a toast but I would like to display these as plain text within my custom UI.

I have raised this issue on the Amplify repo and have been informed there is no way to customise the error messages but it is currently a feature request. In the meantime, I think there must be a workaround.

There are 3 ways I believe I might be able to access the error message in React:

1. When an error is received Amplify sets it in the state of 'Authenticator', which is the parent component (created by the HOC) of my custom UI. Without modifying the actual library I can't pass this down as props or pass it into context/redux but is there some hack to be able to access this?
2. The request to Cognito is handled by a fetch request generated from the library but I can see the response in the console. A 400 response with the error message in the body of the response. Is there a way to set up some kind of event listener to get the error message off the http response?
3. The library also generates a toast when an error message is returned. I am currently passing the HOC a css theme (display: none) to hide this. Is there a way to listen for the creation of the toast component and get the message off the span element that lays inside?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Matthew

Answer (score 4):

I found two ways to solve this issue.

Firstly, if you are only interested in ‘signIn’, ‘signUp’ or ‘signOut’ events. You can use the ‘Hub’ utility to listen for an 'auth' event before you attempt an authentication action like signIn and then set the error message to state. Something like this:

```
import { Hub } from "aws-amplify";

handleLogin = e => {
  Hub.listen("auth", res => {
    const errorMsg = res.payload.data.message ? res.payload.data.message : null;
    this.setState(prevState => ({...prevState, errMsg: errorMsg}));
  })
  this.signIn(e);     
}
```

Alternatively, if like me you want the error messages off confirm sign in or forgot password events. You can use the Auth API and catch the error message. You have to figure out what needs to be passed into each method but the docs are quite informative. Here's an example for the confirm sign in:

```
import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';

confrimSignIn = () => {
        Auth.confirmSignIn(this.props.authData, this.inputs.code, 'SMS_MFA')
        .then(() => this.changeState('signedIn'))
        .catch(err => this.setState({errMsg: err.message}));;
}
```